# How to take maximum name from the files with any .txt extension and remove the other contents expect maximum one using perl?

Tags: perl

In the below code I tried to filter the maximum name from any files in my path and remove the minimum digit contents from the file using Perl.

Content inside all .txt files in my direcctory:

```
sv1     12.70%  12.70%
sv2     49.21%  49.21%
sv3     88.89%  88.89%
sv4     92.06%  92.06%
```

Expectation:

```
sv4     92.06%  92.06%
```

code:

```
use File::Path qw(remove_file);
my $path_output = $output_dir;
find2($path_output);
sub find2{
    my ($s1) = @_;

    my (@dirs1) = grep { -f && /\.txt$/ } glob $s1.'/*';
    print @dirs1;

    my ($link1) = sort{ 
                    my ($m1)=$a1=~m/\/(sv\d+)$/;  my ($n1)=$b1=~/\/(sv\d+)$/; $n1 cmp $m1 
                }  grep{/\/sv\d+$/} @dirs1;

    foreach (@dirs1)
    {
        ($_=~m/sv(\d+)$/ && $_ ne $link1)? remove_file($_) : find2($_);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
"remove_file" is not exported by the File::Path module

print @dirs1 is not printing the matching files.
```

Edited code:

```
my $path_output1 = $output_dir;
#print $path_output1;
find2($path_output1);
sub find2{
    my ($s1) = @_;
print $s1;

    my (@dirs1) = grep { -f && /\.txt$/} glob $s1.'/**/*/*';
#print @dirs1 ;

    my ($link1) = sort{ 
                    my ($m1)=my $a1=~m/\/(sv\d+)$/;  my ($n1)=my $b1=~/\/(sv\d+)$/; $n1 cmp $m1 
                }  grep{/\/sv\d+$/} @dirs1;
#print "****$link1***";
    foreach my $file (@dirs1)
    {
        ($file=~m/sv(\d+)$/ && $_ ne $link1)? unlink($file) : find2($file);
#print $file;
    }
}
```

still i had struck with my query.

Answer (score 3):

The module [File::Path](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Path) does not have a function `remove_file`. Looking at the [Changes document](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/File-Path), it never had. But Perl has a built-in to delete files: [`unlink`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unlink.html).

Get rid of the `use File::Path`, you don't need it. Then use `unlink` in your loop.

```
foreach my $file (@dirs1)
{
    ( $file =~ m/sv(\d+)$/ && $_ ne $link1 ) ? unlink($file) : find2($file);
}
```

Comment: But still i doesnt look any changes in the above code @dirs1 is not printing all files .@simbabque

Comment: @salarinfi I don't understand. Please be more clear. Do you get a new error? If the `print @dirs1` does not output anything, are you sure your path is correct? The `grep` looks fine to me. It should find files if there are some.

Comment: please check the grep line there it is not taking the /\.txt$/ files.How can i fix it. @simbabque.

Comment: $s1 prints the following path /project/files @Simbabque

Comment: Add a `print;` into the block of the `grep` to see what it finds. `grep { print; -f ... }` or just output the return value of the `glob` call directly. **Be careful not to run the loop with the `unlink` in it, it might delete all your files!** (You don't need to highlight me on my own posts, I get notified anyway)

Comment: by giving print it prints the folder name /project/files/regon @simbabque

Comment: @salarinfi if that's all it prints, then there are no files in that folder. Make sure you have the right folder, and that there are files in it.

Comment: actually my file location will be as follows /projects/files/regon/sv/sv.txt .so now i should do the above code for sv.txt .like wise i have multiple .txt files under same regon folder location so the above code should perform for all. @simbabque

Comment: @salarinfi `glob` is not recursive like that. You are better of using File::Find::Rule or similar. Or you can change the pattern for glob to `$s1 . '/**/*`, which will find all files underneath any folder in the `$s1` folder, but not files directly in the `s1` folder.

Comment: Can you able to show me some examples with file::find ::rule @simbabque

Comment: @salarinfi we're moving out of scope for this question. Please read the documentation and search first. There are a lot of questions here that explain how File::Find::Rule works. I've never used it myself, so I would have to read the documentation myself, too.